# AUTOREF error [italian] with \todonotes

Tags: hyperref, languages, todonotes, newtheorem, autoref

The `\autoref` keeps writing "sezione" (section) instead of "Teorema" (Theorem), I've tried different solutions (even the "`%`" one) but they simply don't want to work for me... Here it is a short extract of my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}       
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}\newtheorem{definition}{\todo[inline, inlinewidth=2.3cm, noinlinepar, color=green!40]{Definizione}}[section]

\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{\todo[inline, inlinewidth=1.9cm, noinlinepar, color=red!40]{Teorema}}
%\providecommand*{\theoremautorefname}{Teorema}
%\addto\extrasitalian{\renewcommand{\theoremautorefname}{Teorema}}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{bla}
    Bla bla bla
\end{theorem}
%\begin{proposition}
    Blu blu blu $\implies$ \autoref{bla}.
%\end{proposition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your example errors for me as \theoremstyle is undefined.

Comment: Unrelated, but remember that with a few exceptions `hyperref ` should be loaded last as it has to adapt to packages loaded

Comment: The problem isn't language-specific: besides [italian], it can be replicated with [english] [french] and [ngerman], and indeed without `babel` at all. But only on the condition of removing `\theoremstyle`, as noted by Ulrike.

Comment: Guys, in the extract i forgot to include the package {amsthm} which was already included in my document. So the problem still exists for me.

Comment: todo inserts a phantomsection and this changes the counter name. Don't use it there, if you want nice colored boxes use e.g. tcolorbox.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you load the `amsthm`, `hyperref`, and (new) `cleveref` packages -- in this order -- and only then execute the `\theoremstyle` and `\newtheorem` directives. Next, in the body of the document, I'd like to suggest that you use `\cref` instead of `\autoref` to generate cross-references without having to worry about the (apparent) interactions between the `todo` and `hyperref` packages.

If you load the `cleveref` package with the option `italian`, you automatically get the Italian counterparts of the labels "theorem" and "definition" ("teorema" and "definizione", resp.) as well as the Italian versions of linguistic conjunctions (e.g., "e" instead of "and", etc). [Aside: I've discovered that there is a bug in the Italian language setup commands which, of all things, concerns the labels used with the `definition` environment. In the code below, I suggest inserting the instruction `\crefname{definition}{definizione}{definizioni}` as a pre-emptive bug fix.]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,todonotes}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,italian]{cleveref} % <-- option 'italian'
\crefname{definition}{definizione}{definizioni} % preemptive bug fix

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{\todo[inline, inlinewidth=2.3cm, 
   noinlinepar, color=green!40]{Definizione}}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{\todo[inline, inlinewidth=1.9cm, 
   noinlinepar, color=red!40]{Teorema}}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} 
\begin{theorem}\label{bla} Bla bla bla \end{theorem}
\begin{definition}\label{ble} Ble ble ble \end{definition}

\autoref{bla}   % <-- still incorrect

\cref{bla,ble}  % <-- but \cref is correct
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are two issues. One is that `\todo` somehow clashes with the `\autoref` mechanism; the other one is that you need to use [`aliascnt`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt).

I replaced `\todo` with `tcolorbox` features: this is a specialized package and not a hack like `\todo`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{aliascnt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtcbox{\thmtcbox}[1]{
  colback=#1,
  tcbox raise base,
  left=0.4pt,
  top=0.4pt,
  right=0.4pt,
  bottom=0.4pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}{\thmtcbox{green!40}{Definizione}}[section]

\newaliascnt{theorem}{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[theorem]{\thmtcbox{red!40}{Teorema}}
\aliascntresetthe{theorem}

\providecommand*{\definitionautorefname}{Definizione}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{bla}
Bla bla bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{blu}
Blu blu blu $\implies$ \autoref{bla}.
\end{definition}

\autoref{blu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, `cleveref` is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtcbox{\thmtcbox}[1]{
  colback=#1,
  tcbox raise base,
  left=0.4pt,
  top=0.4pt,
  right=0.4pt,
  bottom=0.4pt,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}{\thmtcbox{green!40}{Definizione}}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[definition]{\thmtcbox{red!40}{Teorema}}
\crefname{definition}{definizione}{definizioni}
\Crefname{definition}{Definizione}{Definizioni}
\crefname{theorem}{teorema}{teoremi}
\Crefname{theorem}{Teorema}{Teoremi}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{bla}
Bla bla bla
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}\label{blu}
Blu blu blu $\implies$ \cref{bla}.
\end{definition}

\Cref{blu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you call

```
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
```

the links will include the name.

[image]

Comment: @Mico Once that I didn't look in the manual… :-)